# Finding a specific character in a string in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab

Suppose I have a string  `'johndoe@hotmail.com'`. I want to store the string before and after "@" into 2 separate strings. What would be the easiest method of finding the "@" character or other characters in the string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used strtok and strrep from Matlab instead.

Comment: -1. The other answers are better here since they provide example code. How did you use `strtok` and `strrep`? Show an example and I'll flip to a +1.

Answer (score 17):

[STRTOK](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/strtok.html) and an index operation should do the trick:

```
str = 'johndoe@hotmail.com';
[name,address] = strtok(str,'@');
address = address(2:end);
```

Or the last line could also be:

```
address(1) = '';
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use **strread**:

```
str = 'johndoe@hotmail.com';
[a b] = strread(str, '%s %s', 'delimiter','@')
a = 
    'johndoe'
b = 
    'hotmail.com'
```

Comment: note: recent versions of MATLAB recommend using `textscan` instead of `strread`

Answer (score 11):

For "easiest",

```
>> email = 'johndoe@hotmail.com'
email =
johndoe@hotmail.com
>> email == '@'
ans =
  Columns 1 through 13
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
  Columns 14 through 19
     0     0     0     0     0     0
>> at = find(email == '@')
at =
     8
>> email(1:at-1)
ans =
johndoe
>> email(at+1:end)
ans =
hotmail.com
```

It would be slightly more complicated if you were looking for something with more than one character, or you weren't sure if there was exactly one @, and in that case MATLAB has a lot of functions for searching through text, including regular expressions (see `doc regexp`).

Answer (score 7):

[TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) works too.

```
str = 'johndoe@hotmail.com';
parts = textscan(str, '%s %s', 'Delimiter', '@');
```

returns a cell array where parts{1} is 'johndoe' and parts{2} is 'hotmail.com'.

Answer (score 5):

If this thread isn't completely enumerated by now, may I add another?  A handy perl-based MATLAB function:

```
email = 'johndoe@hotmail.com';
parts = regexp(email,'@', 'split');
```

parts is a two element cell array similar to mtrw's implementation of textscan.  Maybe overkill, but regexp is much more useful when splitting a string by multiple delimiting characters or pattern searching.  The only downside is the use of regular expressions which I still haven't mastered after 15 years of coding.

Comment: +1 strange that no one mentioned regular expressions this whole time :)

Answer (score -4):

String email = "johndoe@hotmail.com";

```
    String a[] = email.split("@");
    String def = null;
    String ghi = null;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        def = a[0];
        ghi = a[1];
    }
```