# What is the regex for a string that has no pipe (|) character?

Tags: regex

What is the regular expression for a string that should not contain a pipe (|) character? e.g., "this is an example |" of a string with a pipe character.

Comment: `[^|]*` <-- Something like this? What's the language?

Comment: @Jithin: You are rejecting empty string, which is valid.

Comment: @nhahtdh Yeah, thanks for notifying..

Answer (score 5):

Use a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
\A[^|]*\z
```

**Explanation:**

```
\A    # Start of string
[^|]* # Match zero or more characters except |
\z    # End of string
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you don't need a regex to find out if a character is included in a string or not.

You didn't specify a language; e.g. in Perl, you could use the `tr` operator:

```
if( $string !~ tr/|// ) {
   ...
```

or you could just look up the character and check its `index` (-1 if not there):

```
if( index($string, '|') == -1 )
   ...
```

Other languages surely have comparable language constructs ([VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5193893/170194), [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/275944/170194), [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/287373/170194), [Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1425147/170194), [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/) etc.).

Comment: yeah, regexes are evil for this task.

Answer (score 0):

If what you wanted to ask is: what is a regex to match a line that haven't got the pipe symbol then: the answer is: `^[^|]*$`

That is match an entire line of zero or more characters that are not `|`