# How to read in lines of unequal length CSV doubles

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a file where each line is a list of CSV doubles, i.e:

```
80,81,179,180,181,182
114,115,27,31,34
16,17,18,25
63,64,35,58,73,75,76,94,95
67,68
```

I need to read in each line, temporarily store it as a 1 x n double array for some calculations, then move onto the next line.

The idea I had was:

```
fid = fopen('fileName.txt');
tline = fgets(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    % Update with solution I came up with
    values = cellfun(@str2double,regexp(tline,',', 'split'));
    tline = fgets(fid);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search [for the commas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1425170/855869) contained in each line and the either use the indexes of their location in the string or their amount to loop till the end of the line.

Comment: The reply below it seems useful, it creates a cell array of each value, is there an easy way to convert that to a 1 x n vector? `cell2mat` combines all to one long value. EDIT: `cellfun(@str2double,cellArray);`

Comment: @user2680312 the command `tline == ','` will already provide a 1 x n vector.